# How do I debug a running node.js application from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, node-inspector

Node inspector is not working for me, so instead of that, I am trying to debug a node application with Eclipse. I would like to debug a node.js instance that is running via the "npm start" command. However, whenever I debug a node application inside Eclipse, it doesn't debug the running instance, but a new instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, I still haven't figured out how to get node-inspector to work, but I did succeed in debugging a running instance of a locally running node express project by installing the Enide Studio 2014 (Eclipse) plugins and running "debug as Node project". The Enide Studio download is located here:

http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/studio/2014/

**Update**: That being said, you're probably much better off using Intellij/Webstorm or VSCode to develop Node.js applications, the latter is excellent and free.